# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.1 Immediate Windows outputs too much now for non-primitive data structures

Tags: python, output, visual-studio-2019, immediate-window

On Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.1 I get the following problem on the immediate window:

Before version Version 16.8.1

a=[2,3]

a
[2, 3]

After version Version 16.8.1 I get all of this

a=[2,3]

a
[2, 3]

```
    append: <built-in method append of list object at 0x0000028BB0DFC548>

    clear: <built-in method clear of list object at 0x0000028BB0DFC548>

    copy: <built-in method copy of list object at 0x0000028BB0DFC548>

    count: <built-in method count of list object at 0x0000028BB0DFC548>
```

How do I switch off all this unnecessary output? For all non-primitive data structures I get all of this...

Thanks

Eurico